# Unable to convert .pdf to .docx using pdf2docx

Tags: python

I am building a website where the user uploads the file to the frontend, which is uploaded to the firebase storage and in turn calls the backend API in which the url of the website is passed. I want to download the file with that url and then convert the .docx file to .pdf file using the `pdf2docx` library in my backend, and then upload the converted file back to the firebase storage.

But I am facing some issues while converting the file.
Here's my backend code.

```
class PDFManipulationRequest(BaseModel):
    urls: Union[str, List[str]]
    user: Dict = {}
    rename_file: str = ""
    pages: List[int] = []
    rotation: Dict = {}
    password: str = ""
    metadata: Dict

async def pdf_to_word(request: Request, data: PDFManipulationRequest):
    urls = data.urls
    metadata = data.metadata
    filename = metadata["name"]
    filename_without_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

    # Download the PDF file
    response = requests.get(urls)
    pdf_stream = BytesIO(response.content)

    cv = Converter(pdf_stream.read())
    output_doc_stream = BytesIO()

    cv.convert(output_doc_stream, start=0, end=None)
    cv.close()

    # Set the destination path for the file upload
    folder_name = "pdf-to-word/modified"
    destination_path = f"{folder_name}/{filename_without_extension}.docx"

    # Upload the single image file to Firebase Storage
    firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebase_config)
    storage = firebase.storage()
    storage.child(destination_path).put(output_doc_stream.getvalue())

    # Generate the download URL for the modified PDF
    docx_url = storage.child(destination_path).get_url(None)

    # Clean up temporary files
    pdf_stream.close()
    output_doc_stream.close()

    return docx_url
```

Here is a traceback of my error

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 428, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 91, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\cors.py", line 146, in simple_response
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 66, in app 
    response = await func(request)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 237, in app  
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "M:\JavaScript\Pdf Clone\server\app.py", line 243, in pdf_to_word   
    cv = Converter(pdf_stream.read())
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pdf2docx\converter.py", line 43, in __init__
    self._fitz_doc = fitz.Document(pdf_file)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\fitz\fitz.py", line 3989, in __init__  
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: bad filename
```

*Note: I do not want to store the file locally even temporarily, I have just stored that for the last resort since that makes my website very slow.*

Comment: More detail needed to help reproduce and investigate the error.  Could you be more specific as to what issues you are seeing?  Is the program itself raising an exception?  Is it failing to create the .docx file?  Does it a create a .docx file which throws errors when opened?  Does this happen with all PDF files, or just one that you happen to be testing with?   Can you share the URL for any of the files you are testing with?

Comment: I have added a traceback of the error I was getting, and it is happening with all the files. Here is a [URL](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pdf-conversion-a9e40.appspot.com/o/OWrAMsYKQDMZhKWwf0gTE2XHHvK2%2Fupload%2FPython%20Viva%20Questions.pdf?alt=media&token=b0d72002-766e-4f2f-a66f-77da8cecb7b4) of a pdf file which I was testing with. And probably the error is happening with the `Converter` function.

Comment: what is the format and content of the `request` and `data` parameters?  Or better yet, can you provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  The provided code can't be run standalone without that information.   It's not clear if `data.urls` is a single url or a list of urls.

Comment: Apologies if I am unable to explain the question properly, I edited the question again showing what `data` has and `data.urls` has only a single url like the one I mentioned earlier to you. I am downloading the document from the url, converting it into a `BytesIO stream`, then passing that to the Converter function, and in there I am getting the `TypeError`.